# Populate query result with missing dates

Tags: sql, oracle

hy, curently I have something like this in results

```
date          amount       amount2
27.11.2014    100           100
28.11.2014    100           100
29.11.2014    100           200
1.12.2014     100           700
2.12.2014     100           100
```

I dont have any records for today and 30.11.2014.

I need to find a way to write for those days too, to get the final result like

```
date          amount       amount2
27.11.2014    100           100
28.11.2014    100           100
29.11.2014    100           200
30.11.2014    0             0
1.12.2014     100           700
2.12.2014     100           100
3.12.2014     0             0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just left join your query to a virtual table that contains all necessary dates.
Such a table can be obtained quite easily:

```
   with t as (
        select to_date('01.12.2014', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + level -1 date_
        from dual 
        connect by to_date('01.12.2014', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + level -1 <= to_date('05.12.2014', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
   ) 
 select t.date_,
        nvl(<your_table>.amount1,0) amount1,
        nvl(<your_table>.amount2,0) amount2
 from t left join <your table> yt on yt.date = t.date_
```

This query brings you all the dates between Dec 1 and Dec 5, you can amend the range by youself. 
Hope this helps, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: Yes, but you might want to show an example connecting this virtual table to what he has.  Side note - A permanent physical table containing all dates (and various pieces extracted to columns and indexed) are **incredibly** useful, probably the best analysis table you can create.  For instance, being able to aggregate months via an indexable range query, instead of calling a function on the column.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, thanks, I did it. And yes, physical calendars are extremely useful.